# paper-shadow disrupts desired layout

Tags: layout, dart, polymer

Consider this markup:

```
<custom-element horizontal layout>
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div flex><i>space</i></div>
    <paper-toggle-button></paper-toggle-button>
</custom-element>
```

Where `custom-element` is declared like this:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-element" noscript>
    <template>
        <paper-shadow z="1">
            <content flex></content>
        </paper-shadow>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

The middle `div` with the `flex` attribute is supposed to fill all available space, but does not if the `paper-shadow` is present. Here is a comparison (top is with the `paper-shadow`):

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution while typing the answer, so here it is:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-element" noscript>
    <template>
        <paper-shadow flex horizontal layout z="1">
            <content flex></content>
        </paper-shadow>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```